# Amazon EC2 Plugin for Jenkins: ERROR: Unable to launch the agent for EC2

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

The Jenkins controller is unable to launch slave nodes on EC2 instances started by Amazon EC2 plugin.
The log shows Java being installed that ends up as follows:

Public IP, no root folder specified:

```
  ....
  xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.5-21.amzn2                                     
  xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.5-9.amzn2                                     

Complete!
Nov 06, 2022 1:54:40 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Verifying: which scp
/usr/bin/scp
Nov 06, 2022 1:54:40 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Copying remoting.jar to: /tmp
Nov 06, 2022 1:54:40 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Launching remoting agent (via SSH client process): ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/ec2_12318726237497378155_known_hosts" -o "HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-ed25519" -i /tmp/ec2_11819376404929797195.pem ec2-user@34.238.85.80 -p 22  java  -jar /tmp/remoting.jar -workDir /tmp
[11/06/22 13:54:40] Launching agent
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/ec2_12318726237497378155_known_hosts" -o "HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-ed25519" -i /tmp/ec2_11819376404929797195.pem ec2-user@34.238.85.80 -p 22  java  -jar /tmp/remoting.jar -workDir /tmp
ERROR: Unable to launch the agent for EC2 (jenkins-ec2-plugin-slave) - jenkins-ec2-plugin-slave (i-0cddd80399db92097)
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:459)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:404)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:437)
    at hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:170)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.ssh.EC2UnixLauncher.launchScript(EC2UnixLauncher.java:270)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2ComputerLauncher.launch(EC2ComputerLauncher.java:48)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:298)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:48)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
command-line line 0: unsupported option "accept-new".
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Launching instance: i-0cddd80399db92097
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: bootstrap()
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Getting keypair...
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Using private key j2 (SHA-1 fingerprint e4:b8:50:f9:87:5c:cb:e6:0d:c1:e2:99:0a:08:eb:db:08:6e:c5:a7)
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Authenticating as ec2-user
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to 34.238.85.80 on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connection allowed after the host key has been verified
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:52 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:53 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: connect fresh as root
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:53 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connecting to 34.238.85.80 on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:53 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connection allowed after the host key has been verified
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:53 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:53 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Creating tmp directory (/tmp) if it does not exist
Nov 06, 2022 1:58:53 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Verifying: null -fullversion


HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

URI:    /computer/EC2 (jenkins-ec2-plugin-slave) - jenkins-ec2-plugin-slave (i-0cddd80399db92097)/logText/progressiveHtml
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    Stapler
```

Private IP, no root folder specified:

```
  ....
  xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.5-21.amzn2                                     
  xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.5-9.amzn2                                     

Complete!
Nov 06, 2022 1:39:09 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Verifying: which scp
/usr/bin/scp
Nov 06, 2022 1:39:09 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Copying remoting.jar to: /tmp
Nov 06, 2022 1:39:10 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Launching remoting agent (via Trilead SSH2 Connection):  java  -jar /tmp/remoting.jar -workDir /tmp
ERROR: unexpected stream termination
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:459)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:404)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:437)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.ssh.EC2UnixLauncher.launchScript(EC2UnixLauncher.java:283)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2ComputerLauncher.launch(EC2ComputerLauncher.java:48)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:298)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:48)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

URI:    /computer/EC2 (jenkins-ec2-plugin-slave) - jenkins-ec2-plugin-slave (i-0137aefa185f5bc64)/logText/progressiveHtml
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    Stapler
```

```
+ jenkins --version
2.361.3
+ java --version
openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1) (build 11.0.16+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1) (build 11.0.16+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
Amazon Linux 2 Kernel 5.10 AMI 2.0.20221004.0 x86_64 HVM gp2
Amazon EC2 plugin Version 2.0.3
```

Tried changing security groups and roles, private and public IP settings with an ec2-user root folder and other settings.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the Amazon EC2 plugin installs Java 8:

```
INFO: Verifying: java -fullversion
bash: java: command not found
Nov 06, 2022 1:38:45 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud
INFO: Installing: sudo yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

The new Jenkins version 2.361.3 requires Java 11. In the section **Init script** add the following commands to install Java 11 (Amazon Linux/RHEL):

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum upgrade -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11 -y
```

*For Ubuntu use apt instead.*

*For Amazon Linux 2023:*

```
sudo yum install java -y
```

NOTE: If you are installing Maven on **Amazon Linux 2/2023** using the command:

```
sudo yum install maven -y
```

it may try to install the **java-17-amazon-corretto** package as a dependency. To avoid conflicts with other Java packages, you can exclude the installation of Java.